# I am successfully displaying my data using "withObservables()" method but it's still not reactive to my component in WatermelonDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs, watermelondb

**Hello Everyone!**

In the [WatermelonDB docs](https://nozbe.github.io/WatermelonDB/Components.html) you can make your component reactive with `withObservables()` method, it will update or re-render your component every time the data changes.

**In my code**

I have basic user data that has been stored to WatermelonDB, and the result when I am `console.log()` that data is:

```
{
  "__changes": {
    "_isScalar": false, 
    "_value": [Circular], 
    "closed": false, 
    "hasError": false, 
    "isStopped": false, 
    "observers": [], 
    "thrownError": null
  }, 
  "_hasPendingDelete": false, 
  "_hasPendingUpdate": false, 
  "_isCommitted": true, 
  "_isEditing": false, 
  "_raw": {
    "_changed": "", 
    "_status": "created", 
    "city": "NY City", // The data that I added
    "id": "rddcv3ttt9s03jel", // The data that I added
    "name": "John Doe", // The data that I added
    "user_id": 0 // The data that I added
  }, 
  "_subscribers": [], 
  "collection": {
    "_cache": {
      "map": [Map], 
      "recordInsantiator": [Function anonymous], 
      "tableName": "user"
    }, 
    "_subscribers": [], 
    "changes": {
      "_isScalar": false, 
      "closed": false, 
      "hasError": false, 
      "isStopped": false, 
      "observers": [Array], 
      "thrownError": null
    }, 
    "database": {
      "_actionQueue": [ActionQueue], 
      "_actionsEnabled": true, 
      "_isBeingReset": false, 
      "_resetCount": 0,
      "_subscribers": [Array], 
      "adapter": [DatabaseAdapterCompat], 
      "collections": [CollectionMap], 
      "schema": [Object]
    }, 
    "modelClass": [Function User]
  }
}
```

With `withObservables()` method I can display that data, and here's my code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Button, Layout} from '@ui-kitten/components';
import WATERMELON from '../models';
import util from '../utils';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import withObservables from '@nozbe/with-observables';
import {Text} from '../components/Helper';

const enhance = withObservables(['user'], props => {
  return {
    user: props.user,
  };
});

const UserBasicInfo = enhance(props => {
  // Successfully displaying the data but not Reactive
  return (
    <>
      <Text>{props.user.name}</Text> {/* John Doe */}
      <Text>{props.user.city}</Text> {/* NY City */}
    </>
  );
});

const TestScreen = props => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await WATERMELON.action(async () => {
        const user_collection = WATERMELON.collections.get('user');
        const fetch_userdata = await user_collection.find('rddcv3ttt9s03jel');
        console.log(fetch_userdata);
        setUser([fetch_userdata]);
      });
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <View>
        <Text>Hello Test Screen!</Text>

        {user !== null && <UserBasicInfo user={user} />}

        <Button
          onPress={async () => {
            await WATERMELON.action(async () => {
              const user_collection = WATERMELON.collections.get('user');
              const userd = await user_collection.find('rddcv3ttt9s03jel');
              await userd.update(user => {
                // Just want to change the city
                // And it's just fine BUT not reactive :(
                user.city = 'Chicago';
              });
            });
          }}
        >
          Press It
        </Button>
      </View>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default TestScreen;
```

**My models/user.model.js**

```
import {Model} from '@nozbe/watermelondb';
import {field} from '@nozbe/watermelondb/decorators';

export default class User extends Model {
  static table = 'user';

  @field('name') name;
  @field('city') city;
}
```

**My models/index.js file**

```
import fs from 'react-native-fs';
import {Database} from '@nozbe/watermelondb';
import SQLiteAdapter from '@nozbe/watermelondb/adapters/sqlite';
import schema from '../schema/watermelon.schema';
import userModel from './user.model';
import customerModel from './customer.model';
// First, create the adapter to the underlying database:
const adapter = new SQLiteAdapter({
  schema,
  dbName: `${fs.DocumentDirectoryPath}/restronic`, // optional database name or file system path
  // migrations, // optional migrations
  synchronous: true, // synchronous mode only works on iOS. improves performance and reduces glitches in most cases, but also has some downsides - test with and without it
  // experimentalUseJSI: true, // experimental JSI mode, use only if you're brave
});

// Then, make a Watermelon database from it!
const db = new Database({
  adapter,
  modelClasses: [userModel, customerModel],
  actionsEnabled: true,
});

export default db;
```

I dunno what's wrong with my code, I just follow the tutorial in the [Docs](https://nozbe.github.io/WatermelonDB/Components.html) but it's still not reactive :(

**Update**

I try with `.subscribe()` method and still not reactive and even worse it's not re-rendering the component when I `setState()` inside that method, The method is running well when I am trying `console.log()` inside that method

```
const UserBasicInfo = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(props.user);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = props.user.subscribe(newVal => {
      // Not re-rendering the component
      setState(newVal);
    });
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  });

  return <>{state !== null && <Text>{state.name}</Text>}</>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'observe()' in the end, it will work

```
const enhance = withObservables(['user'], props => {

return {
    user: props.user.observe(),
  };
});
```

Comment: Not working for me. It showing subscribe is undefined